# KMeans where there are clusters of data with different densities

Tags: clustering, k-means

Suppose we have $n$ data samples and they are grouped in two sets such that half of the data are in a high density region and the other half is in a low density region. These regions are apart from each other. We want to perform KMeans algorithm with $k>2$ to cluster this data. What is expected of the number of centroids in each set after performing the algorithm?

In other words do we expect the same number of centroids near each set or the set with higher density is going to have more centroids around it or vice versa?

Comment: I think this question is unrelated to the number of centroids topic. So, are you saying that you have 2 datasets and want to perform a separate K means on each? Or you don't know which case belong to which set, so you are going to do a single K means on the complete dataset?

Comment: @ttnphns Hi It's the later case that you mentioned. We don't know which sample belongs to which set and yes it's a single K-means.

Comment: So, it looks like you are expecting some clusters to have much greater variance inside than other clusters. K-means is not good way to go then: it implies approximately equal variances ("physical sizes") of clusters. Hierarchical clustering would be better as it gathers clusters agglomeratively. However, if your clusters are _very_ much separated (distant, relative their sizes), K-means is still usable.

Comment: Hierarchical Ward's method has the same objective function as K-means does, and it uncovers clusters of unequal physical sizes better than it.